# Code First Entity Framework Slow When Properties are Missing

Tags: frameworks, ef-code-first, entity

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3.1 Code First.

I have a pretty simple expression and entity model.

```
using (var PMCtx = new PMContext("PMEntities"))
{        
     var results =
            PMCtx.Fetch<vwSDHOriginalMW>()
            .Where(x => x.DT >= StartDate && x.DT < EndDate)
            .ToList();
     return results;
}

public class vwSDHOriginalMW : IEntityObject, IPMContext
{
    public int Schedule { get; set; }
    public DateTime DT { get; set; }
    public int HE { get; set; }
    public Decimal OrgMW { get; set; }        
    public Decimal DELIVERMW { get; set; }
    public string NERCCode { get; set; }
    public string NERCCodeStatus { get; set; }
    public int SDHSDHID { get; set; } 
}
```

This was taking 15 seconds every time, not just the first time.  The model is mapped to a view in a Sql Server 2008 database.  I output the query that EF was sending, and ran it in SSMS and it took a fraction of a second.

Why is this so slow in Entity Framework?

IEntityObject appears to be a marker interface so that the original programmer could be sure these were the only that get put into the generic.

EDIT 1
Fetch ends up going through some layer wrappers to get to the data layer where it does this:

```
private DbSet<TEntity> FetchSet<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IEntityObject
{
        Type PassedType = typeof(TEntity);
        if (!CheckedTypes.Any(x => x.FullName == PassedType.FullName))
            if (!PassedType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => CtxInterfaces.Contains(x)))
                throw new ArgumentException("Type passed is not a DbSet type of constructed context.");
            else
                CheckedTypes.Add(PassedType);

        return privateContext.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

Cleaned up example of the query EF is sending

```
SELECT  [Schedule], 
    [DT], 
    [HE], 
    [OrgMW], 
    [DELIVERMW], 
    [NERCCode], 
    [NERCCodeStatus], 
    [SDHSDHID], 
    [ScheduleDeliveryHourHistoryID]
FROM    [vwSDHOriginalMW]
WHERE ([DT] >= '2/17/2013') AND ([DT] < '2/21/2013')
```

EDIT 2
The view in the database actually had one more column than my entity model had properties. 
I added the property to the model.

```
public class vwSDHOriginalMW : IEntityObject, IPMContext
{
    public int Schedule { get; set; }
    public DateTime DT { get; set; }
    public int HE { get; set; }
    public Decimal OrgMW { get; set; }        
    public Decimal DELIVERMW { get; set; }
    public string NERCCode { get; set; }
    public string NERCCodeStatus { get; set; }
    public int SDHSDHID { get; set; } 
    //missing property
    public int ScheduleDeliveryHourHistoryID { get; set; }

}
```

After adding the property yesterday, it sped up tremendously for a while, ran in 4 seconds instead of 15.  But today it's slow again, and nothing has changed.

UPDATE:
I have narrowed it down a little further.  There are two methods that I can use that end up using the same FetchSet.  The one that I am using returns an IQueryable instead of an IEnumerable.  This seems normal, and since I am filtering afterward, most desirable.  However the method that returns IQueryable takes 15 seconds while the IEnumerable takes less than a second.  (I am calling ToList() on both)  FetchAll turns out just to be a wrapper that calls Fetch and returns IEnumerable instead of IQueryable

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Fetch<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, Common.IEntityObject
{
    return privateContext.Fetch<TEntity>();
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> FetchAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, Common.IEntityObject
{
        return privateContext.FetchAll<TEntity>();
}
```

If I change

```
IEnumerable<vwSDHOriginalMW> results =
                   PMCtx.Fetch<vwSDHOriginalMW>()
                   .Where(x => x.DT >= StartDate && x.DT < EndDate)
                   .ToList();
```

to

```
IEnumerable<vwSDHOriginalMW> results =
                   PMCtx.Fetch<vwSDHOriginalMW>()
                   .ToList()
                   .Where(x => x.DT >= StartDate && x.DT < EndDate);
```

it is fast.  But this isn't acceptable, because it seems like I would want my where clause to be passed to the database.  In this case on a dev environment the view is only 180 rows, but it has potential to be millions, so I definitely don't want to return all my results into memory before I filter them.

Comment: What is the "IEntityObject" for? Have you lazy loading disabled? What is a sample SQL that is being generated? What is you Fetch method like?

Comment: Updated original post.  IEntityObject is just an empty marker interface.  Other details are in the post.

Comment: I missed this part.  Yes, it looks like lazy loading is disabled.  Turning it on didn't have any effect.  The view only has 184 rows anyway.

Comment: There must be a reason why you are adding to CheckedTypes, but try getting the entity set from the database without generics first to see how fast it is: e.g. PMCtx.YourEntitySet.Where(x => x.DT >= StartDate && x.DT < EndDate).ToList(); If that works fast and it should, we can work on the Generic method.

Comment: Updated the post.  Even after making a few privates public so that I could access the Set directly it was still slow.  However I did make a strange discovery that makes no sense to me that I explained in my update.  As for CheckedTypes, this doesn't appear to be used for anything functional.  Looks like waste code to me.  Any time it is used it just checks to see if the passed in type is there and if it isn't it adds it.

Comment: It ended up being a problem with indexes and a bad cached execution plan on the database.  I will post the solution tomorrow since it says I don't have enough rep to answer my own question within 8 hours of asking it.

Comment: oh no, indexes of course! I always miss that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging and many headaches, I figured out that the view was referencing a view on a different database instance that referenced a table that was missing a non-clustered index.  This caused the execution plan to get cached incorrectly.  After adding the index on the other database:

```
USE [OTHERDATABASE]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ScheduleEnergyProfileJoin]
ON [dbo].[WTXS_ScheduleEnergyProfile] ([SEQSDR])
INCLUDE ([SEQSEPI],[StartDate],[EndDate])
GO
```

Then clearing the execution plan cache on the database with the view I'm using:

```
USE [MYDATABASE]

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

The query is running quickly.  So it turns out that the SQL that EF said it was using was probably not the sql that was getting sent to the database.  Moral of the story is I should have gone through whatever hoops to get profiling permissions on this database instead of relying on the following to output the SQL that would actually be sent.

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<vwSDHOriginalMW>)results).ToString();
```